# How to insert XML Prolog <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>to Rest XML response in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, xml, rest, spring-boot

How to insert XML Prolog to Rest XML response in Spring Boot Application.

I am using jackson xml dataformat in spring boot rest api.

My Current rest-xml response is:

```xml
<Response>
     <person id = "hello">
        <name>xyz</name>
     </person>
</Response>
```

while I want :

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <person id = "hello">
        <name>xyz</name>
     </person>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this would help somebody: to have a complete solution, took the answer from Sambit, tweaked it a bit and wrote the following utility class. Note that convertPojoToXmlString() return an XML string which could then be sent back to the caller:

```
package com.xml.util;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

import com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxInputProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

/**
 * @author ekariyev
 *
 */
public class XmlUtil {

    private final static XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();

    static {
        xmlOutputFactory.setProperty(WstxInputProperties.P_RETURN_NULL_FOR_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE, true);
    }

    /**
     * @param object
     * @return
     * @throws XMLStreamException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws FactoryConfigurationError
     */
    public static String convertPojoToXmlString(final Object object) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {

        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        try {
            final XMLStreamWriter sw = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);
            final XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

            sw.writeStartDocument();

            mapper.writeValue(sw, object);

            sw.writeEndDocument();

            sw.flush();

        } finally {
            stringWriter.close();
        }

        return stringWriter.toString();

    }

}
```

The solution worked with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It works out of the box even with latest version of Jackson data format (2.13.2)

Answer (score 0):

As of jackson-dataformat-xml version 2.9.0 cannot handle XML Prolog. This is a limitation. To achieve you have two options.

1. You have to use JAXB and annotate your POJO with proper annotations.
2. Generate the XML as String using XMLStreamWriter using Jackson 2 to generate the XML with prolog. I provide below the code outline.

> ```
> StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
> XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
> XMLStreamWriter sw = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);
> XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
> sw.writeStartDocument();
> sw.writeStartElement("root");
> mapper.writeValue(sw, YourPojoBean);
> sw.writeComment("Some comment");
> sw.writeEndElement();
> sw.writeEndDocument();
> ```

For more details, refer this article.
https://dzone.com/articles/solving-the-xml-problem-with-jackson

Comment: Should we return it as String in rest response?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for spring boot.
add two class as the following:

```html
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdvice;

@ControllerAdvice
public class XmlPrologResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> converterType) {
        System.out.println("---------check the xml reponse class---------");
        System.out.println(returnType.getGenericParameterType().getTypeName());

        // Check if the API endpoint is the one you want to target
        // Replace "your/api/endpoint" with the actual endpoint you want to target
        String endpoint = returnType.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(endpoint);

        if (endpoint.equalsIgnoreCase("SwSaController") && !returnType.getMethod().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("GetEncodeBody")) {
            // Ensure this advice is only applied for XML responses
            MediaType mediaType = returnType.getGenericParameterType().getTypeName().equals("jp.pacific.sw.sa.response.CommonResponse") ?
                                  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML : MediaType.TEXT_XML;
            return mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) || mediaType.equals(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        // Retrieve the underlying HttpServletResponse
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse = ((ServletServerHttpResponse) response).getServletResponse();

        // Set the Content-Type header with the XML prolog
        servletResponse.setContentType(selectedContentType.toString() + ";charset=UTF-8");

        // Write the XML prolog to the response output stream
        try {
            servletResponse.getOutputStream().write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>".getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle the exception if necessary
        }

        // Return the original body
        return body;
    }
}
```

```html
@Configuration
public class ApiWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter< ? >> converters) {
        // Create the XML message converter
        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml().createXmlMapper(true).build()
            );

        // Set the supported media types
        MediaType[] supportedMediaTypes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML};
        xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(supportedMediaTypes));

        // Add the XML message converter to the list of converters
        converters.add(xmlConverter);
    }
}
```